# Exim, Debian 12 (bookworm): Tainted '..Maildir/' (file or directory name for maildir_local_delivery transport) not permitted

Tags: linux, debian, exim, debian-bookworm

I have this Exim transport that works just fine on Debian 10:

```
maildir_local_delivery:
  driver = appendfile
  group = mail
  maildir_format = true
  create_directory = true
  directory = /home/${local_part}/Maildir/
  mode_fail_narrower = false
  delivery_date_add = true
  envelope_to_add = true
  return_path_add = true
  mode = 0660
```

On Debian 10 this just delivers mail to local user.

However, on Bookworm it results in this Exim log:

```
2023-09-18 16:13:01 1qiEzk-0003F9-1M == exampleuser@example.com R=localuser T=maildir_local_delivery defer (-1): Tainted '/home/exampleuser/Maildir/' (file or directory name for maildir_local_delivery transport) not permitted
```

I found Exim is unable to create `Maildir` directory in user's home on Bookworm.

This is my `etc/group`:

```
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:clamav,dovecot,Debian-exim
news:x:9:
uucp:x:10:
man:x:12:
proxy:x:13:
kmem:x:15:
dialout:x:20:
fax:x:21:
voice:x:22:
cdrom:x:24:
floppy:x:25:
tape:x:26:
sudo:x:27:
audio:x:29:
dip:x:30:
www-data:x:33:
backup:x:34:
operator:x:37:
list:x:38:
irc:x:39:
src:x:40:
shadow:x:42:
utmp:x:43:
video:x:44:
sasl:x:45:Debian-exim
plugdev:x:46:
staff:x:50:
games:x:60:
users:x:100:
nogroup:x:65534:
systemd-journal:x:999:
systemd-network:x:998:
crontab:x:101:
input:x:102:
sgx:x:103:
kvm:x:104:
render:x:105:
netdev:x:106:
systemd-timesync:x:997:
messagebus:x:107:
_ssh:x:108:
plocate:x:109:
uuidd:x:110:
Debian-exim:x:111:clamav,zabbix
tcpdump:x:112:
ssl-cert:x:113:
bind:x:114:
nut:x:116:
debian-spamd:x:117:
dovecot:x:115:
dovenull:x:118:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to replace

```
  directory = /home/${local_part}/Maildir/
```

with

```
  directory = /home/${local_part_data}/Maildir/
```

At least that is the first thing I found on

https://mox.sh/sysadmin/tainted-filename-errors-in-exim-4.94/

that fits to your config